# Basic functions in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't get the second function can someone help me what does the second function do I got this in solo learn Please explain to me in very basic way as I am a beginner and

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def do_twice(func, x, y):
    return func(func(x, y), func(x, y))

a = 5
b = 10

print(do_twice(add, a, b))
```

Comment: What is the result? Why is it confusing? Update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python supports *higher order programming*: you can pass a function as an argument (actually Python does not care about the type when you pass arguments).

So what happens if you call `do_twice(add, a, b)`? Well you call `do_twice` with `function = add`, `x = 5` and `y = 10`. Now we inspect the body of `do_twice`:

```
return func(func(x,y),func(x,y))
```

The Python interpreter will interpret this statement, and first evaluate `func(x,y)` (the left one). So it calls `add(5,10)`. I assume that you understand how the `add` function works, so that function returns `15`. Next Python evaluates `func(x,y)` (the right one), so it again calls `add(5,10)` which evaluates in `15`.

Finally it calls `func(15,15)`, since `func = add`, it thus calls `add(15,15)` which will result in `30`. This is the result that is returned.

If you would have called `do_twice` with a *lambda expression* like:

```
do_twice(lambda x,y: x+2*y,5,10)
```

the result will thus be: `75`. Because `(lambda x,y:x+2*y)(5,10)` is `25` and `(lambda x,y:x+2*y)(25,25)` is `75`.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. Thanks I finally got it because of you.

Answer (score 1):

You could also write your second function like this:

```
def do_twice(func, x, y):
    val1 = func(x, y)
    val2 = func(x, y)
    val3 = func(val1 , val2)
    return val3
```

That way you are basically just storing the result of each of the 3 calls to `func` in a temporary variable (val1, val2, val3).

Now if you call `print(do_twice(add, a, b))` with your values 5 and 10 the following happens:

```
def do_twice(func, x, y):
    # x = 5, b = 10
    val1 = func(x, y)
    # val1 = 5+10 = 15
    val2 = func(x, y)
    # val2 = 5+10 = 15
    val3 = func(val1, val2)
    # val3 = 15+15 = 30
    return val3
```

Comment: but does func mean add because we never created a variable that assigns func to add in my code or does it just mean the function above

Comment: functions are also objects in python that can be passed to other functions as parameters. by calling ``print(do_twice(add, a, b))`` you are passing the function ``add`` as parameter to ``do_twice`` - but **inside** ``do_twice`` the parameter is now called ``func`` (as per declarion of ``def do_twice(func, x, y):`` the first thing you pass to the function is referenced by the parameter ``func``). But ``func`` still refers to the function ``add``. Thus by executing ``func(x, y)`` inside ``do_twice`` it's the same as executing ``add(x, y)``.

Answer (score 0):

The second simply takes the first function and applies the supplied inputs to it. Such that do_twice takes a function called func. func requires two positional arguments to work an example of a func is add() that requires x and y. so do_twice() takes add() and supplies x and y to it then returns the answer. do_twice is hence returning add(add(x, y), add(x, y))